# Move textview in some layout

Tags: android

I want to move some textview in some layout,how to check that user drag textview in specific position or not.
Like[image]

I wan to drag "yes!" in yellow layout but how to check.

Comment: What do you mean with drag?

Comment: I mean drag text from grey layout to yellow layout with fingure Namenlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement touch listener on your text view. and also implement

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             // when u will touch ur textview.
             break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
             //ur text view is moving
             break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             // when u release ur finger after dragging
             // in this method check if x and y are within ur yellow layout bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply - set all items to ONE layout and implementing onTouchListener of parent layout. `View.setX()/setY()` if you use android 11 or above.